# Why don't I get the emoji aliases in python?

Tags: python-2.7

I am working in pydev with python 2.7 and anaconda. I want to change the emojis by the aliases. I have installed emoji, but when I run the examples i get the same emoji instead of the alias.

Here is the code:

```
import emoji
print(emoji.demojize('Python is '))
```

The output is: `Python is`

I want the output to be: `"Python is thumbs_up:"`

Please help identifying the problem

Answer (score 0):

In python 2, `'Python is '` is a byte string. The `emoji.demojize` function expects a unicode string. Try `print(emoji.demojize(u'Python is '))`